# Export table to csv to multiple files based on column from different table

Tags: mysql

I need to dump a table into multiple files based on the column value in another table.

I also want to just use the mysql commmand line, not through any scripting language. Is it possible?

E.g.:

Table A has

`(ID, Name, Stuff)`,  `Name` unique

Table B has

`(ID, Name, Start, End)`

I want to dump all the rows in B whose `Name` exists in `A`, each to its own file based on the `Name`.

In SQL, roughly like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM B
WHERE Name = 'brad' (exists in A)
INTO OUTFILE '/home/csv/brad.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

except for each and every name that exists in A.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure `Name` exists in table `A` just join `A` and `B` on name:

```
SELECT *
FROM B
INNER JOIN A ON B.Name = A.Name
WHERE Name = 'brad'
```

As for varying the `OUTFILE` name, I don't think there's a way to do that without programming/scripting. You can do it with a MySQL procedure using `EXECUTE`; there's a bare-bones example [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?97,23677,62359#msg-62359) that you can adapt. The general approach would be to create a cursor of distinct names, then scan it and build/execute the SQL (including the `OUTFILE` value) for each name.